# How can I add orders to the US walmart marketplace that will show in there released orders api?

Tags: walmart-api

I'm a developer trying to integrate the walmart marketplace orders api into a website. I have been using there sandbox which works well enough to a point. I want to actually try adding orders of real items that we've added in walmart but I'm unaware of a way to create test orders so that they would then show in the /v3/orders/released api. Is there no way to create orders like that using the API? Do I just actually purchase our items using walmart site and then cancel orders?

I was going to try their fulfillment api but our account isn't setup to use that since we fulfill the order ourselves.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to create test/dummy orders, but as you said, you can publish a few items and place an order yourself to test them and cancel it later.